# Using FLoops for parallelization in julia

Tags: parallel-processing, julia

I am trying to run this loop using floops for parallelization. However, I am unable to push or append the data to an array.

```
a=[]
b=[]
@floop for i in 1:10
    @reduce() do (r_df=filter(row-> row.col1==1, df))
    result=mean(r_df.col3)
    push!(a, result)
    push!(b, i)
    end
end
```

I tried using `@reduce` macro on the appending the data but it doesn't work. Any suggestion how to make this loop work?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is multi-threaded pushing into an array can't be done in parallel since parallel means it can happen in any order. What you want is

```
a=zeros(10)
b=zeros(10)
@floop for i in 1:10
    @reduce() do (r_df=filter(row-> row.col1==1, df))
    result=mean(r_df.col3)
    a[i] = result
    b[i] = i
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks @OscarSmith for the suggestion. However, this throws an error, `LoadError: matching non-exhaustive`. Any idea why is this happening?